# Lucene query does not match regex characters in content

Tags: java, lucene

Given below is the code snippet I wrote to match a lucene index content. This code works for query with term "loop_" but it does not work for query with term "loop*". Details are given below.

Am trying to figure out how to get this to work:

```
public class TryLuceneQuery {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Version v = Version.LUCENE_48;
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(v);
        Directory fsDir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:\\data\\index"));

        IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(fsDir);
        System.out.println("The index has " + reader.maxDoc() + " documents.");
        for(int i=0;i<reader.maxDoc();i++) {
            Document d = reader.document(i);
            System.out.println(d.get("csv"));
        }


        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        QueryParser parser 
            = new QueryParser("csv",analyzer);

        Query finalQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop_"));

        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(finalQuery,500);
        System.out.println(hits.totalHits + " documents found.");
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = hits.scoreDocs;

        for (int n = 0; n < scoreDocs.length; ++n) {
            ScoreDoc sd = scoreDocs[n];
            float score = sd.score;
            int docId = sd.doc;
            Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
            String code = d.get("csv");
            System.out.println(code);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

The output when I run the above code is:

> The index has 2 documents. 
>   loop<= loop* loop= loop* 
>   loop_ loop< loop! loop+
>   1 documents found. 
>   loop_ loop< loop! loop+

So, the code works for "loop_". Similarly, I want it to work for "loop*" also. If I change the query to "loop*", I get the following output:

> The index has 2 documents.
>   loop<= loop* loop= loop*
>   loop_ loop< loop! loop+
>   0 documents found.

The field "csv" is a TextField.

I tried two ways:

```
Query finalQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop*"));
```

and

```
Query finalQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop\\*"));
```

How should I query to match "loop*"? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try loop\\*? Please refer to following [link](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)

Comment: Yes, I did try. As mentioned in "Query finalQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop*"));". I do not want to use QueryParser.parse(...). I need a TermQuery to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the analyzer.  `StandardAnalyzer` attempts to create meaningful words from full-text content.  Mostly, punctuation is treated as delimiters between words, and are eliminated from the terms in the index.  The reason it works for "loop_" is that underscores are sometimes handled differently than most other punctuation (so are periods and commas, for instance, when found in numbers, see [UAX #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)).

So, when you index these fields with StandardAnalyzer, you get the following tokens:

- loop<= loop* loop= loop* ==> 'loop', 'loop', 'loop', 'loop'
- loop_ loop< loop! loop+ ==> 'loop_', 'loop', 'loop', 'loop'

The `TermQuery` you've constructed manually is not subject to the analyzer, so it's looking for a literal term "loop*", which simply doesn't exist in the index.

It sounds like what you are looking for is to simply break the terms up at spaces.  To do that, you can just use [`WhitespaceAnalyzer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/WhitespaceAnalyzer.html), and reindex your documents.

Then you should see:

- `new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop_"));` => 1 document
- `new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop*"));` => 1 document
- `new TermQuery(new Term("csv","loop"));` => 0 documents!

Comment: Thank you. Changing standard analyzer to whitespaceanalyzer worked.